# Dell D630 light sensor and backlight in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, dell-latitude, backlight

Is there a way to make Windows 7 aware of the light sensor built in the laptop? Also, there doesn't seem to be any way to control the backlight of the LCD from the OS (only the Fn + Up/Down key work). Is there a workaround available?

Comment: I have a D830 with Windows 7 and the Auto mode works fine (Fn+Left arrow)

Comment: If you press START + X, do you see a place to adjust your screen brightness? I don't see this with my laptop. Perhaps the D830 uses a different method to control the brightness, like APIC.

Answer (score 2):

Just looked on Dell.com for you and it does not look like Windows 7 is supported / drivers are not yet available.

If you look at the [driver page (Vista x64)](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WV64&osl=EN&catid=-1&impid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=LATITUDE+D630&hidos=WW1&hidlang=en&TabIndex=) / [driver page (Vista x86)](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WLH&osl=EN&catid=-1&impid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=LATITUDE+D630&hidos=WV64&hidlang=en&TabIndex=), you may have luck with the Vista drivers, but obviously I can't guarantee it.

I see no drivers directly saying light control, but there are a few optional packages such as what is listed as "Dell utility - Notebook system software" that may have controls in for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but none of the software offered on the page resolves this issue.

Comment: Well, I said Windows 7 is not supported yet... That page is your best bet as I am sure that when Dell start offering support for it, it will be there.

Comment: Dell will never offer W7 support for that model, too old.   http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&docid=DSN_360683&isLegacy=true#Issue0_1

Answer (score 1):

Ambient light should be automatically adjusted, there is a setting in the BIOS that will allow this. All of the D620/D630s I have came with that setting off. There is also a max brightness setting I found useful. All seem to be set quite low as a power saving measure. For me the screens seem a bit dim so I crank up that max level.

Answer (score 1):

The ambient light sensor is disabled by default in the BIOS.  Also, it is disabled when your D630 is plugged in.  Only works when on battery.